# Why does my code to send e-mail from python looks much simpler than others?

Tags: python, email

For example this is my simple python code to send e-mail:

```
import smtplib
import getpass
mail = "example@example.com"
passs = getpass.getpass("pass: ")
sendto = "example1@example2.com"
title = "Subject: example\n"
body = "blabla\n"
msg = title + body
send = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.example.com",587)
send.ehlo()
send.starttls()
send.login(mail,passs)
send.sendmail(mail,sendto,msg)
```

and it works perfectly, but whenever i search for sending emails from python much more complicated code shows up, much more modules and lines, but they do the same thing! Why is that? Is my code good or bad?

Comment: What does your code do when the SMTP server is down?

Comment: its pretty much useless then. Do you wan't to say that others work even if the smtp server is down or?

Comment: It gets complicated when you want to send something other than a text message. Then you have to deal with MIME, multipart messages, encodings and etc...

Comment: Other code may handle the situation better when the SMTP server is down, e.g., failing gracefully.

Comment: so this code can't be used to send attachments?

Comment: @SimeonVisser that's not the complicated code i was talking about, i can add  `try` and `except` and it will fail gracefully, if that's what you meant

Comment: No, it can't. email started out as a text only service that was very simple amd was also limited in how much you could send. It expanded with many non-standard extentions and finally settled on MIME encoding which is kind of complicated and requires more coding.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way i can upvote your comment or something? This is pretty much the answer i was looking for, i have google for other questions ^_^

Comment: I'll toss in as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email started as a simple text service but has expanded over the years to include rich content such as html formatting and attachments. The entire message needs to be assembled into a blob of data that old email gateways can still understand so the MIME standard was invented. MIME lets you build a multipart message with each part tagged with encoding hints that are hopefully understood by the email reader on the other end. MIME was so successful that its encodings are used all over the place.

The complicated part of generating email is assembling a MIME message, not just a simple text message.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
import yagmail 
yag = yagmail.SMTP(username) # passw by getpass
yag.send('example@example.com', "subject", "blabla")
```

With added bonus of sending files, html and attachments without effort.